# A question on computing $\int_0^\infty e^{-ix^2} dx$

Tags: complex-numbers, improper-integrals

The standard way to compute
$$\int_0^\infty e^{-ix^2} dx$$
runs via the substitution $z^2 = ix^2$, i.e. $z = \sqrt i x = \frac{1+i}{\sqrt 2} x$, giving
$$\frac{1-i}{\sqrt 2} \int_0^\infty e^{-z^2} dz \quad.$$
The latter integral (right half of the *Gaussian* integral) is "known" to be equal to $\frac{\sqrt \pi}{2}$ giving the final result
$$\frac{\sqrt \pi (1-i)}{2\sqrt 2} \quad .$$
What is missing for me: I can only find proofs/computations of the Gaussian integral over the real domain, but here $z = \frac{1+i}{\sqrt 2} x$ is complex (for real $x$), running along the first median in the complex number plane. Further analysis seems to show that this integral only converges for $z$ with
$$\arg z \in [0,\frac{\pi}{4}] \cup [\frac{3\pi}{4},\frac{5\pi}{4}] \cup [\frac{7\pi}{4},2\pi]$$
and always to $\frac{\sqrt \pi}{2}$.
(Outside these intervals the integral diverges because of $\Re(z^2) \to -\infty$ for $x \to \infty$.)

How to prove that
$$\int_0^\infty e^{-z^2} dz = \frac{\sqrt \pi}{2} $$
for all complex $z$ running along $t e^{i\phi}$, $t$ real and $\phi$ in the above specified intervals?

Comment: For $0\leqslant\phi\leqslant\pi/4$, apply Cauchy integral theorem to $\int e^{-z^2}\,dz$ along the boundary of the sector $0<|z|<R,\ 0<\arg z<\phi$, and take $R\to\infty$. Similarly for other values of $\phi$.

Comment: @metamorphy haha - it is really that simple! But I feel it is an important part of the derivation, because it does not work for all $z$ / paths - and it seems this argument is often neglected.